# reload .vimrc after any :edit command

Tags: vim, editor

I have a section in my .vimrc file that sets the title of the terminal to the name of the file that is opened with vim. However, this breaks down when using `:edit` to go from one file to the next from within vim, as it stays the same. I gather that this is because, by default, the .vimrc file is only run when vim is launched.

**Is there a way to get vim to "watch" for the :edit, :e, and any other commands, and then run `:so $MYVIMRC`, which reloads the .vimrc?**

Alternatively,is there some built in feature that set the terminal title to the file name which I've somehow overlooked?

---

Section mentioned in .vimrc

```
  " Apply filename to terminal session title
  "" Doesn't work when changing file using :edit

  let path_list = reverse(split(expand("%:p"),"/"))

  if len(path_list) > 0
     let &titlestring = path_list[0]
      if &term == "screen"
          set t_ts=^[k
          set t_fs=^[\
      endif
      if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
        set title
      endif
 endif
```

Answer (score 5):

This does this job

```
autocmd BufEnter * :so $MYVIMRC
```

---

**Update**

As suggested by Doktor, it's better to do this in a function, and just call this upon BufEnter. Here's how that works.

---

```
function SetTitle()
    let path_list = reverse(split(expand("%:p"),"/"))

    if len(path_list) > 0
        let &titlestring = path_list[1] . "/" . path_list[0]
        if &term == "screen"
            set t_ts=^[k
            set t_fs=^[\
        endif
        if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
          set title
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * :call SetTitle()
```

Comment: You should put the logic in a function, and call the function in the autocmd not reloading your whole vimrc